# Run python script in servlet via tomcat not working

Tags: java, python, servlets, tomcat9, html-to-pdf

I made a servlet in tomcat9 and placing it ajax call but the python script won't get executed.

My code:

```
package com.thinking.machines.myServices.servlet;

import com.thinking.machines.myServices.database.*;
import com.thinking.machines.myServices.pojo.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import com.google.gson.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HtmlToPdfServlet extends HttpServlet {
    static String filepath = "..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\cgi\\html_to_pdf.py";

    public static void generatePDF(String link) {

        System.out.println("hello hi");
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python",filepath,link);
                Process p = pb.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String link = request.getParameter("data");
        generatePDF(link);
        System.out.println(link);

    }
}
```

The output I see is - hello hi (in tomcat server) but the python script is not executed.
I have also configured the tomcat's conf/web.xml file.

But it works fine for me when I simply just do it without servlet thing and use it with the command line.

here is python code:

```
import sys
import pdfkit
arg=sys.argv[1]
print(arg)
pdfkit.from_url(arg,'..\\result\\google.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use concurrency API over plain Threading in webapps, or any managed env. Or better, speciy an executor in tomcat/webapp context, and use it.

About the issue, do you get any specific error(please provide stacktrace if any)? Make sure that `python` is visible from tomcat's path. Because you can run the `python` from cmd/terminal, it doesn't mean tomcat could does the same thing.

simply try to call the `python` as absolute path, so let say `python` is located at `/usr/bin/`, so go for `/usr/bin/python` instead of `python`.

Another possible issue could be becasue of blocked IO(due to limited buffer) over child process.

Each process you create(like `Process p = pb.start();`) has two streams, one for input, and one for output.

Now if the `python` print something(that is `inputstream` in java side), and there is no read over `inputstream`, then process gets freezed(not always), until stream buffer gets free by otherside(java in your case)

You may simply redirect the output to `nul`, or a file instead of parent(java) caller, and see what happens.
e.g.

```java
Process p = pb.start();
InputStream _is=_p.getInputStream();
int _r;
while((_r=_is.read())!=-1){//keeps the buffer free always
     //use or ignore it
}
```